# why const value's name instead of `this`

Tags: javascript

I am learning [airbnb coding style](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). Why use `atom.value` instead of `this.value` in the following codes (section 3.3)? any benefits?

```
// good
const atom = {
  value: 1,

  addValue(value) {
    return atom.value + value;
  },
};
```

**Update**

The following code is an example of its benefits. Any other benefits?

```
const bias = atom.addValue;
console.log(bias(11))
```

Thanks

Comment: Haven't looked at the docs, but they possibly prefer the use of `atom` because `this` is ambiguous depending on the scope. Using `atom` is a clear indication of the scope intended.

Comment: @CarlMarkham I got this just now.

Comment: @BAE Yeh, `this` and `atom` in this context would be the same thing, just code readability really.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `this` it will refer to `addValue` scope:

```
addValue(value) {
  return this.value + value;
}
```

Here `this` will not refer to `atom` but the `addValue()` which does not have any `value` attribute.

```js
const atom = {
  value: 1,

  addValue(value) {
    console.log( atom.value + value);
    return atom.value + value;
  },
};

atom.addValue(20);
```

Comment: @MysteryDownvoter why the downvote?

Comment: `this` refers to the global object. You can see this by editing your snippet to use `this.value + value` the result will be the same.

Comment: The `addValue` *scope* is not a JS object. Did you mean the *call context*?

Comment: @Bergi possibly, terminology isn't my strong point.

Comment: regardless, `this` does not refer to the method and using `this.value` is essentially the same as `atom.value`. Seems like personal preference on their part